# Django Group migrations don't persist on db even when using --reuse-db

Tags: python, django, pytest, pytest-django

My Django app creates some Groups via migrations. I'm having issues with pytest not finding the Groups when using the `--reuse-db` flag.

My understanding was: migrations get applied before pytest runs, and although the tests get executed in a transaction to roll back any database changes, the db gets cached and those migrations persist (if using the `--reuse-db` flag).  But that's not happening here.

To repro my problem:

- if I run a test with the `--create-db` flag, it has no problem with any Group it needs to access
- if I switch to `--reuse-db` flag, and run the test twice, the second time fails with a `Group.DoesNotExist` error:

```
====================================================================================== short test summary info ======================================================================================
FAILED /test/something.py::test_defaults - django.contrib.auth.models.Group.DoesNotExist: Group matching query does not exist.
FAILED /test/something.py::test_create - django.contrib.auth.models.Group.DoesNotExist: Group matching query does not exist.
FAILED /test/something.py::test_get - django.contrib.auth.models.Group.DoesNotExist: Group matching query does not exist.
============================================================================= 3 failed, 1 passed, 116 warnings in 2.57s ===================================================================
```